# jQuery and iFrame detecting new height after HTML injection

Tags: jquery, iframe

I have an iFrame which I am setting the HTML dynamically through jQuery like so.

```
$("#iframe").contents().find('body').html("This is a large HTML string");
```

Which works great. But now my height doesn't work to adjust the height of the iFrame. I'm guessing its getting the height before the DOM change not after. How do I get the new height now with the new HTML? I don't even think the .load event is even firing. Here is what I have so far:

```
$("#iframe").load(function () {
   //alerting this new height returns nothing
   $("#iframe").contents().find('body').height();
});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use method chaining

```
$("#iframe").contents().find('body').html("This is a large HTML string").height()
```

Comment: This is the solution. All others seem to get the height correctly but before the DOM has changed not after. Chaining the height seems to be the way to get the height once the DOM has changed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The [html method](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2) sets the contents based on the HTML passed in as an argument.  If you want it to fire the `load()` event, you should be using the [load method](http://api.jquery.com/load/) instead.  In addition, you can use a [callback function](http://api.jquery.com/load/#callback-function) with `load()` if you don't want to rely on events.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using jQuery you can create a callback function that will fire after the iframe chain is complete. Just a demo you can take it where you want from here.

```
var callbacks = $.Callbacks();
callbacks.add( createIframe );
callbacks.fire( getHeight() );

function createIframe() {
 $("#iframe").contents().find('body').html("This is a large HTML  string");
}

function getHeight() {       
   alert( $("#iframe").contents().find('body').height() );
}
```